# cdk watch command never returns

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm following the workshop provided by aws, https://cdkworkshop.com/20-typescript/30-hello-cdk/300-cdk-watch.html.
When I issue

```
$ cdk watch
```

After the command is succeeded, it never returns. I can see that the new function is deployed correctly on the aws console. But it seems like it didn't finish normally.
When I issue

```
$ cdk deploy --hotswap
```

I get no error. It deploys and returns cleanly.

Anyone knows or experiences the same?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [expected behaviour](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html).  *"watch mode (cdk deploy --watch, or cdk watch for short) continuously monitors your CDK app's source files and assets for changes and immediately performs a deployment of the specified stacks when a change is detected"*.

Watch mode is a common CLI idiom.  Typescript's `tsc --watch`, works similarly, for instance, continuously compiling to `js` as you make changes.